# How can I securely generate secret-sharing/multisig keys on a p2p network?

Tags: multi-factor, secret-sharing, p2p, financial, zero-trust

I am trying to create a peer-to-peer escrow system. I need to encrypt the private key of a wallet with a 2-of-3 secret-sharing function - the buyer, seller, and arbitrator will each have have one key.

The problem lies in the generation of secret keys on a p2p network, as there is no trusted server. What can I do to prevent a maliciously modified client from making a copy of the keys before distributing them to their rightful owners?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If buyer, seller, and arbitrator are all using the same client and are all "peers", where peers are potentially untrusted and might use a malicious client, there is no one person to trust.

Also, the premise of having one client generate 3 keys and distributing them to others, and then deleting them is a weak premise. The client need only find one way of *not* deleting an item and this premise falls.

Another option might be to just encrypt something for each of the other 2 using public keys.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. What I meant is: how can I generate these keys securely? Is it possible for a client to never see them? And what do you mean by "just encrypt something for the other 2"? That's what I'm trying to do, but like you said; anything being encrypted has to be viewable to the encrypter, who is in this case a possibly malicious client.